# Question about proof that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the union of an at most countable collection of disjoint segments. (2.29 Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis

The exercise 2.29 in Rudin is to prove that every open set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the union of an at most countable collection of disjoint segments.

Intuitively I find it hard to understand how an open set in $\mathbb{R}^1$ can be a union of *disjoint* segments. It seems some points will be left out, unless you consider the whole set itself.

I found a proof where the idea is to construct a set $I_x$ for every $x\in E$ in the following manner.

Let $a = \inf\{z \mid (z, x) \subset E\}$ and $b = \sup\{y \mid (x, y) \subset E\}$ and let $I_x = (a, b)$.

Then you show that $E$ is the union of those sets $I_x$ and that they are disjoint. You also show that they are countable. I'm confused however, because to me it seems that $I_x$ is in fact the entire set $E$. Am I wrong? Really grateful if someone can help me understand why $I_x$ is not equal to $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that $I_x$ may not be the set $E$ is if $E=(-2,-1)\cup(1,2)$, or something like it. To show that the set of all distinct sets $I_x$ is countable (at most), consider the density of the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

$I_x$ is an interval. All you need for $I_x$ not to be equal to $E$ is for the open set not to be an interval. $(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ will do the trick. It requires two disjoint intervals, say $I_{1/2}$ and $I_{3/2}$.

Comment: Thank you both (Matt and @Alex S). In my mind I was only considering $E$ to be a connected set. This makes it all a lot clearer.

Comment: @Jarvi79 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what Rudin means by segments, but every open subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals.  Finite collections of open intervals are countable still, or if you want to think of the empty set as a degenerate open interval (that is, an interval with the same left and right endpoint but not including that end point), then if your open set $E$ is really just the union of a finite number of disjoint open intervals $I_1, \ldots, I_n$, you can still interpret this as $E = \cup_{j = 1}^{\infty} I_j$ where $I_j = \emptyset$ for all $j > n$. Now, for the general case, we can index such a collection of disjoint open intervals by the rational numbers.  To see what I mean, I would recommend looking at Proposition 0.21 in Folland's real analysis book.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! I didn't have a problem with the proof itself - I could follow every step of the argument. I was just confused about the construction since I was only considering connected subsets of $R^1$.

Comment: That used to be the exact problem I had when I first heard of this theorem!

Comment: That used to be the exact problem I had when I first heard of this theorem!